# Showing translated ACF field names within WordPress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

i'm using ACF PRO with WPML, field names are translated right in the backend but when i try to show them (using a single-content.php) on the frontend, i can't get the translated field names' values. Is there a way in the template to force to get the translated field names, to show language1 translation when you are in language1 and to show language2 translation when you are in language2. Googleing i found something about hardcoded text. I'm using this to show the content (in spanish):

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 120%; color: black;"><?php if( get_field('telefono_de_contacto') ): ?><p><strong>Teléfono de contacto: </strong> <?php the_field ('telefono_de_contacto'); ?></p><?php endif; ?></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 120%; color: black;"><?php if( get_field('email_de_contacto') ): ?><p><strong>Email de contacto: </strong><?php the_field ('email_de_contacto'); ?></p><?php endif; ?></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 120%; color: black;"><?php if( get_field('oficio') ): ?><p><strong>Oficio: </strong><?php the_field ('oficio'); ?></p><?php endif; ?></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 120%; color: black;"><?php if( get_field('municipio') ): ?><p><strong>Municipio: </strong> <?php the_field ('municipio'); ?></p><?php endif; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I had the same issue working with ACF Pro and WPML. The below code worked for me.

***Option1:***

In the below code, Change the LANGUAGE CODE inside the IF condition based on your language and use the the_field code to display that specific language field.

```
<?php 

if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "en")
{
the_field ('telefono_de_contacto'); 
} 
elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "es")
{ 
the_field ('telefono_es_contacto'); 
}
else
{
the_field ('telefono_fr_contacto'); 
} 

?>
```

***Option2:***

You can create a function in functions.php like below.

```
function cl_acf_set_language() {
  return acf_get_setting('default_language');
}
function lg_opt($name) {
    add_filter('acf/settings/current_language', 'cl_acf_set_language', 100);
    $option = get_field($name, 'option');
    remove_filter('acf/settings/current_language', 'cl_acf_set_language', 100);
    return $option;
}
```

And then you can use the below code in the template file to call the acf field dynamically.

```
<?php language_code(lg_opt('email_address_en'),lg_opt('email_address_fr'),lg_opt('email_address_zh')); ?>
```

My website has 3 languages. English, French and Chinese. So the above code is based on this order.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will give it a try. Best wishes.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if this works for you.